# allign video and canvas side by side in HTML5

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML file using Video Tag and canvas Tag . How can i allign them side my side with CSS. The current sample code is added [here](http://jsbin.com/qibemuxuxo/1/)

How can i allign the Video Tag and Canvas tag side by side as in the screenshot below

Current Screen Design :

[image]

Expected Screen Design
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A few additional tags and pseudo-element `::after` will help you.

See here: [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/14qg8jqf/3/show/) & [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/14qg8jqf/3/)

Comment: not sure why the result is not working in both chrome and firefox

Comment: It's weird, should works. Try to change `.clearfix` styles, see [code](http://jsfiddle.net/14qg8jqf/4/)